# How do I query a mysql database for a file in php and then send the response?

Tags: php, mysql, http, select

I would like to have the PHP look up a document in a mysql table and then send out an http response.  The response will later be used in a iPad app.  the only response I get from this PHP to my app is: <>

Not helpful... Any ideas?  Thanks so much!

```
<?                                                              
$username=$_GET['user'];
$password=$_GET['secret'];
$database="db";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE documentId='2'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
dataT = @mysql_result($result, 0, "Document");   
$name = @mysql_result($result, 0, "DocumentTitle");
$size = @mysql_result($result, 0, "DocumentSize");
$type = @mysql_result($result, 0, "DocumentType");

header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
echo $dataT;

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You need a $ in front of dataT. Is that just a typo when including the code here?

Comment: Thanks so much... I really should have seen that.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $ in front of

```
dataT = @mysql_result($result, 0, "Document");
```

missing.

Please activate all error reportings, i.e. `E_NOTICE` - then you would see such errors yourself and early.

Comment: oh bother! Thanks so much - I'll look into the E_NOTICE thing.